# Can a mobile application built with Cordova (not PhoneGap) be compiled on Adobe website?

Tags: ios, cordova

I am building Mobile applications under Windows 7 and I am trying to compile for iOS.

I have to use Cordova 3.5.0 because the latest PhoneGap, the 3.4.0

Will not do the job for me.

Can an application designed with Cordova, not PhoneGap, be compiled for iOS on Adobe PhoneGap website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no.

In your case, no. This is because you need to use 3.5 and Build does not currently support 3.5

You can with most projects, create a new `config.xml` that has all of the extra config tags for Build (plugins, icons, platforms, etc.), zip your `www` folder and upload to PGBuild.

I say most because you can't upload plugins that you made, or plugins that aren't supported on PGBuild. And you have to remember that the `config.xml` you use for Cordova is not the same as the `config.xml` you will need for PGBuild.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Do you recommend Hackintosh and installing xcode inside hackintosh?

Comment: I have not tried this so I cannot recommend, sorry. It sounds like it could work though.